# Yiibooster TbButton url link not work

Tags: php, yii, yii-booster

i want the button link to another web page, i'm using following code in my view file:

```
    $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton',array(
    'context'=>'primary',
    'label'=>'button',
    'url'=>'www.baidu.com'
    ));
```

and the html it generated as following:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="yw2" name="yt0" type="button">button</button>
```

the following code worked but show as a string:

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('button'),'www.baidu.com')
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 6):

here is the solution:

```
 $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton',array(
   'context'=>'primary',
   'label'=>'button',
   'buttonType' =>'link',
   'url'=>'href link XXXXXXX.com'
));
```

**buttonType** is the solution.
It's not documented , just reading API....
bye

Answer (score 0):

just replace your url to this:

'url'=>'http://www.baidu.com'